# Existe alguna alternativa para Raspberry pi y conectar SSH bajo NAT?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

Estimados, me encuentro trabajando en un proyecto con RPI3 y conectado a una Banda Ancha Móvil 3G, que tiene bloqueados los puertos 22 SSH, existe alguna opción de crear un tunnel mediante web, para poder tener acceso al SSH de la máquina?

Saludos.

Comment: ¿ Y no será mas fácil cambiar el puerto en el que escucha el servidor SSH ?

Comment: Bueno, da igual. Échale un ojo a [`shellinabox`](https://github.com/shellinabox/shellinabox). Está para Debian, si no recuerdo mal.

Comment: @Trauma te refieres a cambiar el puerto ssh de la configuración?, eso no me funciona... :/

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo usar un producto comercial, se trata de **Dataplicity** https://www.dataplicity.com/ .

Es gratuito para 1 dispositivo y lo que hace es crear un tunel a través de su web sin problemas de puertos ni nada. Podrás acceder a tu Raspberry usando el software de esta empresa para Android o iOS o través de una shell web.
También permite redirigir el puerto 80 a una dirección mapeada en su web de forma gratuita. Igualmente si quieres mapear otros puertos (torrent,syncthing,...) necesitas usar la versión de pago.

Comment: Al final termine usando un tunnel con SSH desde el Server principal.

Comment: Mucho mejor si lo pudiste hacer de una forma tan directa. Lo que yo comenté es una solución comercial pero que es muy fácil de usar y es capaz funcionar en casi cualquier configuración de red.